# Редирект после нажатия на кнопку

Tags: javascript

У меня есть такой код (см. ниже). Этот файл срабатывает во время загрузки страницы и перекидывает меня как надо на http://site.com/uk/ , но вот когда на самом сайте я нажимаю на кнопку с ссылкой http://site.com/ru/  он меня перекидывает на http://site.com/uk/ опять . Если в URL строке прописать http://site.com/ru/  то спокойно зайдет , но вот по нажатию на кнопку , то перекидывает на  http://site.com/uk/  Помогите, пожалуйста, как это можно было бы исправить?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.location.href = "/uk/"

             document.getElementsByClassName("wp-block-button__link").onclick = function () {
                    location.href = "http://site.com/ru/";
                };



        </script>
        <title>Page Redirection</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: window.location.href = "/uk/" у вас срабатывает при каждой загрузке страницы, если код приведенный выше находится на странице /uk/ он постоянно её перезагружает

Comment: код находится даже до папок с основными файлами (Использую Wordpress)

Comment: я понял. Он переходит во время каждой загрузки как я понял . Надо чтобы по нажатию переходил туда на /ru/. Если в js файле своего кода я пропишу , чтобы по нажатию перехдил на /ru/ нечего не меняется

Comment: ну если успеете нажать) пока он не перейдет на /uk/)) зачем первая строчка  window.location.href = "/uk/"?

Comment: Во время загрузки страницы показывает site.com и  на сайте контент на английском языке по дэфолту. А когда перехожу на русский, то добавляется /ru/   в итоге получается http://site.com/ru/ . Мне надо, чтобы было так же и на uk , а так как uk стоит по дэфолту, то не показывается /uk

Comment: мб нет  этих строк на странице /uk/ document.getElementsByClassName("wp-block-button__link").onclick = function () {
                    location.href = "http://site.com/ru/";
                };

Comment: не понял  немножко

Comment: Проверьте ваш js код присутствует на странице, с которой вы хотите сделать переход на /ru/. Так же скажите какого типа элемент wp-block-button__link ( это <a> или <div> или еще что то). Возможно при нажатии срабатывает не только ваша функция, но и дефольное событие, которое указана в теге, типа атрибут href у тега <a>